# How to work faster with `ionic cordova run browser` command

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic app, I had to install some cordova plugins, due to which `ionic serve` does not work any more. After searching on web I found I need to work with:

`ionic cordova run browser`

Now if I make changes then I need to close the cli, open it and need to run the command again. `Ctrl + F5` , clearing cache or refreshing browser nothing takes effect of the changes.

Every time I do a little update I have to run this command to see the update. Is there a way I can work faster?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ionic cordova run`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/) command has a livereload option which

> Spin up server to live-reload www files

Do:

```
ionic cordova run browser -l
```

Comment: it runs  on localhost:8100 , when i try to login its says uncaught error, cordova not available , but on localhost:8100/index.html it works fine but does not get refresh  :(  , Please advise

Comment: for which plugin does it say cordova not available? does it show when you run the command without livereload?

Comment: It shows when I run with - l,  if I run this without - l then it works fine

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2306 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2719 there seem to be some issues with livereload..and also there is https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2312

Comment: this can save developers time